# visual studio 2010 solution hangs for about 1 min every time I save even editing minor changes in report

Tags: visual-studio-2010, save

"visual studio 2010 solution hangs for about 1 min every time I save even editing minor changes in report" this happens every time but only on one solution, my other visual studio 2010 solutions are are in same folder works fine.

Comment: you can say it hangs for 1 min while attempting to save .rpt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved by my self
Crystal reports > Design > PageSetup > Check "**noprinter**" Option
this will increase speed dramatically